# Insert/Update multiple records from single form submission

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We are passing multiple records through a form submission and inserting them into a data extension. Currently, only a single record is added and does not loop through to add the remaining records. Here's our current setup

```
<!-- ET Logic -->
%%[ 
/* ExactTarget AMPscript */
@ActionDate, @ActionDateTime

SET @ActionDate = Now()
SET @ActionDateTime = SystemDateToLocalDate(@ActionDate)

set @Send_id = RequestParameter('jid')
set @JobID = RequestParameter('jid')
set @ListID = listid
set @BatchID = _JobSubscriberBatchID        
set @EmailName = emailname_
/*set @EmailAddress = EmailAddress*/

Set @ReminderDate = RequestParameter('rd')

If @ReminderDate == "10" THEN
set @CampaignName = "10 Day Appt Reminder"
set @CampaignID = "100"
Set @DELookUp = "03_ApptConfirmation_Lookup" 
Set @DEClinic = "01_ApptConfirmation_Appts"
Set @SegmentCode = "LF"

 ELSEIF @ReminderDate == "3" THEN
 set @CampaignName = "3_Day_Appt_Confirmation"
 set @CampaignID = "124"
 Set @DELookUp = "03_ApptConfirmation_Lookup"
 Set @DEClinic = "01_ApptConfirmation_Appts"
 Set @SegmentCode = "SF"

 ELSE
 set @CampaignName = "Same Day Appt Reminder"
 set @CampaignID = "130"
 Set @DELookUp = "03_ApptConfirmation_Lookup"
 Set @DEClinic = "01_ApptConfirmation_Appts"
 Set @SegmentCode = "SF"

  ENDIF

  Set @familyid = RequestParameter('fid')
  Set @HOHid = RequestParameter('hid')

  Set @FamilyTotal = Rowcount(Lookuprows(@DELookUp,"FamilyID",@familyid))
  Set @GroupRecords =      LookupOrderedRows(@DELookUp,0,"AppointmentDateTime","FamilyID",@familyid)

  If @FamilyTotal == 1 THEN
  Set @Plural = ""
  ELSE
  Set @Plural = "s"     
  ENDIF

   If Rowcount(@GroupRecords) > 0 THEN 

   for @i = 1 to Rowcount(@GroupRecords) do 

   Set @row = Row(@GroupRecords,@i)

    Set @FamilyAppt = Field(@row,"AppointmentID")
    Set @ApptSubscriberKey = Field(@row,"Subscriber Key")
    Set @PatientID = Field(@row,"Subscriber Key")   

    If @i == 1 THEN
    Set @FamilyFirstNames = Propercase(Field(@row,"PatientFirstName"))
    Set @FamilyApptTime = Field(@row,"AppointmentDateTime")
    Set @FamilyApptDay = Format(@FamilyApptTime,"dddd")
    Set @FamilyApptMonth = Format(@FamilyApptTime,"MMM")
    Set @FamilyApptDate = Format(@FamilyApptTime,"dd")
    Set @StartTime = Format(@FamilyApptTime,"h:mm tt")
    Set @ApptDisplay = Concat(@FamilyApptDay,", ",@FamilyApptMonth," ",@FamilyApptDate," at ",@StartTime,"")
    Set @SubjectLineDate = Concat(Format(@FamilyApptTime,"MMMM"),' ',Replace(@FamilyApptDate,"0",""),'')
    Set @ApptClinicID = Lookup(@DEClinic,"ClinicID","AppointmentID",@FamilyAppt)
    Set @FriendlyClinicName = Lookup("ll_clinic_data","FacilityName","CRMFacilityID",@ApptClinicID)

    ENDIF

    Next @i

    ENDIF

    ]%%

    <h1 class="cancel">Can't make your appointment?<br />We're here to help!</h1>
    <div id="internal-wrap">
    <form id="reschedule" method="post" action="http://cl.s6.exct.net/DEManager.aspx" name="reschedule">
        <input type="hidden" name="_clientID" value="7001394" />  
        <input type="hidden" name="_deExternalKey" value="LL_TEST_ET_Appointment_Action" />  
        <input type="hidden" name="_action" value="add" /> 
        <input type="hidden" name="_returnXML" value="0" />  
        <input type="hidden" name="_successURL" value="http://pages.s6.exacttarget.com/page.aspx?QS=5c591a8916642e73860d45fb640e9855bc53db1cd1173d61fa7b9df26551c626" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_errorURL" value="http://pages.s6.exacttarget.com/page.aspx?QS=5c591a8916642e73246dca055088dc864aa78dc2c1070df7207662d502cba6db" />
        <input type="hidden" name="FamilyId" value="%%=v(@familyid)=%%" />
        <input type="hidden" name="PatientID" value="%%=v(@PatientID)=%%" />
        <input type="hidden" name="AppointmentDateTime" value="%%=v(@FamilyApptTime)=%%" />
        <input type="hidden" name="AppointmentClinicID" value="%%=v(@ApptClinicID)=%%" />
        <input type="hidden" name="ActionType" value="Cancel" />
        <input type="hidden" name="ActionDateTime" value="%%=v(@ActionDateTime)=%%" />
        <input type="hidden" name="Campaign_Name" value="%%=v(@CampaignName)=%%" />
        <input type="hidden" name="Send_id" value="%%=v(@JobId)=%%" />
        <input type="hidden" name="EventDate" value="%%= v(RequestParameter('ed'))=%%" />

       %%[If @FamilyTotal > 1 THEN]%%
      <!-- if there are multiple appointments -->
        <fieldset id="radio">
            <label>Would you like to cancel all of your scheduled appointments? </label>
            <input type="radio" name="cancel" value="all" checked /> <strong>Yes</strong>, cancel all of my appointments<br />
            <input type="radio" name="cancel" value="one" /> <strong>No</strong>, cancel only 1 or some of my appointments
        </fieldset>
```

***UPDATED CODE***

```
        <h1 class="cancel">Can't make your appointment?<br />We're here to help!</h1>
       <div id="internal-wrap">
       <form id="reschedule" method="post" action="http://cl.s6.exct.net/DEManager.aspx" name="reschedule">
        %%[
            Set @DELookUp = "03_ApptConfirmation_Lookup"
            Set @GroupRecords = LookupOrderedRows(@DELookUp,0,"AppointmentDateTime","FamilyID",@familyid)

            If Rowcount(@GroupRecords) > 0 THEN 

                for @i = 1 to Rowcount(@GroupRecords) do 

                Set @row = Row(@GroupRecords,@i)

                Set @FamilyAppt = Field(@row,"AppointmentID")
                Set @ApptSubscriberKey = Field(@row,"Subscriber Key")
                Set @PatientID = Field(@row,"Subscriber Key")   

                If @i == 1 THEN
                    Set @FamilyFirstNames = Propercase(Field(@row,"PatientFirstName"))
                    Set @FamilyApptTime = Field(@row,"AppointmentDateTime")
                    Set @FamilyApptDay = Format(@FamilyApptTime,"dddd")
                    Set @FamilyApptMonth = Format(@FamilyApptTime,"MMM")
                    Set @FamilyApptDate = Format(@FamilyApptTime,"dd")
                    Set @StartTime = Format(@FamilyApptTime,"h:mm tt")
                    Set @ApptDisplay = Concat(@FamilyApptDay,", ",@FamilyApptMonth," ",@FamilyApptDate," at ",@StartTime,"")
                    Set @SubjectLineDate = Concat(Format(@FamilyApptTime,"MMMM"),' ',Replace(@FamilyApptDate,"0",""),'')
                    Set @ApptClinicID = Lookup(@DEClinic,"ClinicID","AppointmentID",@FamilyAppt)
                    Set @FriendlyClinicName = Lookup("ll_clinic_data","FacilityName","CRMFacilityID",@ApptClinicID)

                ENDIF
        ]%%       
        <input type="hidden" name="_clientID" value="7001394" />  
        <input type="hidden" name="_deExternalKey" value="LL_TEST_ET_Appointment_Action" />  
        <input type="hidden" name="_action" value="add" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_returnXML" value="0" />

        <input type="hidden" name="FamilyId" value="%%=v(@familyid)=%%" />
        <input type="hidden" name="PatientID" value="%%=v(@PatientID)=%%" />
        <input type="hidden" name="AppointmentDateTime" value="%%=v(@FamilyApptTime)=%%" />
        <input type="hidden" name="AppointmentClinicID" value="%%=v(@ApptClinicID)=%%" />
        <input type="hidden" name="ActionType" value="Cancel" />
        <input type="hidden" name="ActionDateTime" value="%%=v(@ActionDateTime)=%%" />
        <input type="hidden" name="Campaign_Name" value="%%=v(@CampaignName)=%%" />
        <input type="hidden" name="Send_id" value="%%=v(@JobId)=%%" />
        <input type="hidden" name="EventDate" value="%%= v(RequestParameter('ed'))=%%" />
        %%[Next @i]%%
        <input type="hidden" name="_successURL" value="http://pages.s6.exacttarget.com/page.aspx?QS=5c591a8916642e73860d45fb640e9855bc53db1cd1173d61fa7b9df26551c626" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_errorURL" value="http://pages.s6.exacttarget.com/page.aspx?QS=5c591a8916642e73246dca055088dc864aa78dc2c1070df7207662d502cba6db" /> 
        %%[ENDIF]%%

       %%[If @FamilyTotal > 1 THEN]%%
      <!-- if there are multiple appointments -->
        <fieldset id="radio">
            <label>Would you like to cancel all of your scheduled appointments? </label>
            <input type="radio" name="cancel" value="all" checked /> <strong>Yes</strong>, cancel all of my appointments<br />
            <input type="radio" name="cancel" value="one" /> <strong>No</strong>, cancel only 1 or some of my appointments
        </fieldset>

    <div id="cancel-one">
        <p>Fill out our online form below and we'll call you back to confirm which appointments you'd like to cancel.</p>
        <fieldset id="name">
            <input type="text" name="PatientFirstName" placeholder="First Name*" class="required" />
            <input type="text" name="PatientLastName" placeholder="Last Name*" class="required" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="phone">
            <input type="text" name="PrimaryPhoneNumber" id="PrimaryPhoneNumber" placeholder="Phone*" class="required phone" />
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    %%[ELSE]%% 
    <!-- Else (only one appointment) -->
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel" value="all" />
    <!-- end multi appointment if -->
     %%[ENDIF]%%                                                                                                                                       

        <fieldset id="reason">
        <p>Please let us know why you are canceling your appointment</p>
            <select name="cancel_reason" class="required">
                <option value="" selected>Select...</option>
                <option value="scheduling problem">The time and date no longer work for my schedule</option>
                <option value="No longer a patient">I am no longer a Kool Smiles patient</option>
                <option value="No insurance or cannot afford">I don't have insurance or can't afford to see the dentist</option>
                <option value="moved">I have moved</option>

                <option value="other">Other (please explain)</option>
            </select>               
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="cancel-other">
            <textarea name="cancel_reason_other" placeholder="Please explain *" class="required"></textarea>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset id="actions">
            <input type="hidden" name="AppointmentID" value="%%=v(@FamilyAppt)=%%" />
            <input type="submit" value="Cancel my appointment(s)" class="button-green transparent" />
        </fieldset>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the ampscript runs on the server before the page is sent to the browser.  The way you have your FOR loop just changes the values of those three variables as many times as you have rows returned without doing anything else.  The other variables get set by the first row and don't change.  Then your html gets written out withthe variables where they ended up after the loop.  So, your hidden field values get the values from row 4 (if there were 4 rows returned) for the three variables that get set by the one that loops and the rest get set from row 1 from the IF statement inside of the loop.

What you'll want to do is to move your FOR loop down into the HTML and have it output HTML with your values and then have the NEXT @i so that html with the values gets written out.

Here's a simplified version of what you're doing.  Let's assumes I'm pulling back an ordered rowset ordered on the field I'm going to write out and the field values of the rows are 1, 2, 3, 4.

```
%%[ FOR @i = 1 TO RowCount(@rows) DO
    SET @row = Row(@rows, @i)
    SET @result = Field(@row, "Result")
    NEXT @i
%%]
<tr>
  <td>RESULTS</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>%%=v(@result)=%%</td>
</tr>
```

The resulting HTML on the client side will look like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>RESULTS</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>4</td>
</tr>
```

If you move the FOR loop down and little and have it output the values you will get what you want.  See the difference in this code:

```
<tr>
  <td>RESULTS</td>
</tr>
%%[ FOR @i = 1 TO RowCount(@rows) DO
    SET @row = Row(@rows, @i)
    SET @result = Field(@row, "Result")
%%]
<tr>
  <td>%%=v(@result)=%%</td>
</tr>
%%[ NEXT @i ]%%
```

This code will result in the html on the client side looking like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>RESULTS</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>4</td>
</tr>
```

Which is what we were wanting.  I hope that's helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested updates. I've tried a number of different combinations and find that I am still unable to update multiple records based of a single post. I get the same error that the data extension failed to update. I've updated my code in the original post to reflect the updates.

Comment: @Realrx7. I think there are a couple of problems, but the main one I would see is that you're building a form with multiple input fields with the same name.  This is a problem in itself, but all but one of each set of input fields will have blank values (have a look at your rendered html source on the page to see).  From your code it looks like the only thing that's in the html that's in the FOR loop that would be set by the FOR loop is the patientID and the ApptClinicID.  You can move the IF @i==1 out of the loop and move all of its html out of the loop too.

Comment: Now, your loop is still going to generate hidden inputs with the same name and different values and typically the server will just grab the last value if multiple ones with the same name are passed in.  So, you need to figure out a different way of doing that.  I've never used the web collect.  Is there a reason you're using it instead of posting to another landing page?  Let us know if that's a possibility and we can help you with some logic to accomplish what you're wanting with it.  It seems like you'd have a lot more options with it.

Comment: We are using the web collect because that was the original framework for the account. We inherited the setup and are trying to understand their way of doing things. At this point, I think our best option is to do exactly what you are saying and post to another landing page. I don't see the web collect being able to handle multiple records with the current build out.